# Error while trying to PACKAGING a javafx program using jpackage

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jlink, jpackage

I'm planning to package a JavaFX program with jpackager so I find this project on GitHub and download it but when I try to package this project I get an error...

this is what the output looks like with -X switched:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@3c904f1e
[DEBUG]   (s) silent = false
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) stripClassifier = false
[DEBUG]   (s) stripVersion = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useBaseVersion = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useRepositoryLayout = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useSubDirectoryPerArtifact = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useSubDirectoryPerScope = false
[DEBUG]   (s) useSubDirectoryPerType = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Copying javafx-graphics-14.0.1.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\javafx-graphics-14.0.1.jar
[INFO] Copying javafx-base-14.0.1.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\javafx-base-14.0.1.jar
[INFO] Copying jmetro-11.6.12.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\jmetro-11.6.12.jar
[INFO] Copying javafx-graphics-14.0.1-win.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\javafx-graphics-14.0.1-win.jar
[INFO] Copying javafx-base-14.0.1-win.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\javafx-base-14.0.1-win.jar
[INFO] Copying module2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\module2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Copying javafx-controls-14.0.1.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\javafx-controls-14.0.1.jar
[INFO] Copying module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\module1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Copying javafx-controls-14.0.1-win.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\libs\javafx-controls-14.0.1-win.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ main-ui ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3764951d]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) artifact = com.dlsc.jpackagefx:main-ui:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) attachedArtifacts = []
[DEBUG]   (f) createChecksum = false
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/AL-AWAL/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = jar
[DEBUG]   (f) pomFile = C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) updateReleaseInfo = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\target\main-ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\jpackagefx\main-ui\1.0-SNAPSHOT\main-ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\jpackagefx\main-ui\1.0-SNAPSHOT\_remote.repositories
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\pom.xml to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\jpackagefx\main-ui\1.0-SNAPSHOT\main-ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\jpackagefx\main-ui\1.0-SNAPSHOT\_remote.repositories
[DEBUG] Installing com.dlsc.jpackagefx:main-ui:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\jpackagefx\main-ui\1.0-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-local.xml
[DEBUG] Installing com.dlsc.jpackagefx:main-ui/maven-metadata.xml to C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\jpackagefx\main-ui\maven-metadata-local.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (Build Native Windows App) @ main-ui ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=308100, ConflictMarker.markTime=193000, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=93, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=211600, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=186200, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=39, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1954100, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=78, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=122447500, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=2975500}
[DEBUG] org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.6.0
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:4.12:test (scope managed from default) (version managed from default)
[DEBUG]             org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]          org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:jar:1.6.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11
[DEBUG]   Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3764951d]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) addOutputToClasspath = true
[DEBUG]   (f) addResourcesToClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) async = false
[DEBUG]   (f) asyncDestroyOnShutdown = true
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathScope = runtime
[DEBUG]   (f) environmentVariables = {APP_VERSION=1.0.0, PROJECT_VERSION=1.0-SNAPSHOT}
[DEBUG]   (f) executable = build_app.bat
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/AL-AWAL/.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]
[DEBUG]   (f) longClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) longModulepath = true
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginDependencies = [org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.6.0:, org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile, backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.6:runtime, org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile, commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile, classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile, org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20:compile, org.apache.commons:commons-exec:jar:1.3:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.dlsc.jpackagefx:main-ui:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) remoteRepositories = [      id: central
      url: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => false, update => daily]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => daily]
]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@3c904f1e
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) toolchain = jdk
[DEBUG]   (f) workingDirectory = C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop\Files\java project\JPackageScriptFX\jpackagefx-main
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] env: =::=::\
[DEBUG] env: ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
[DEBUG] env: APPDATA=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Roaming
[DEBUG] env: APP_VERSION=1.0.0
[DEBUG] env: ASL.LOG=Destination=file
[DEBUG] env: COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
[DEBUG] env: COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
[DEBUG] env: COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
[DEBUG] env: COMPUTERNAME=NAMEER242
[DEBUG] env: COMSPEC=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
[DEBUG] env: DRIVERDATA=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
[DEBUG] env: DXSDK_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\
[DEBUG] env: FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
[DEBUG] env: FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
[DEBUG] env: HOMEDRIVE=C:
[DEBUG] env: HOMEPATH=\Users\AL-AWAL
[DEBUG] env: IDEA_INITIAL_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\Desktop
[DEBUG] env: INTELLIJ IDEA COMMUNITY EDITION=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin;
[DEBUG] env: JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\HS jdk-14.0.2
[DEBUG] env: LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local
[DEBUG] env: LOGONSERVER=\\NAMEER242
[DEBUG] env: NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
[DEBUG] env: ONEDRIVE=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\OneDrive
[DEBUG] env: ONEDRIVECONSUMER=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\OneDrive
[DEBUG] env: OS=Windows_NT
[DEBUG] env: PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\HS jdk-14.0.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable\flutter\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\010 Editor;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\gradle-5.4.1\bin;C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.3\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\bin;;C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_1.17.5-stable\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin;;C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\AL-AWAL\.dotnet\tools
[DEBUG] env: PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
[DEBUG] env: PROCESSOR_REVISION=8e0a
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
[DEBUG] env: PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files
[DEBUG] env: PROJECT_VERSION=1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] env: PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
[DEBUG] env: PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
[DEBUG] env: PYCHARM=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\bin;
[DEBUG] env: PYCHARM COMMUNITY EDITION=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.4\bin;
[DEBUG] env: SESSIONNAME=Console
[DEBUG] env: SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
[DEBUG] env: SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINDOWS
[DEBUG] env: TEMP=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Temp
[DEBUG] env: TMP=C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Temp
[DEBUG] env: USERDOMAIN=NAMEER242
[DEBUG] env: USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=NAMEER242
[DEBUG] env: USERNAME=NAMEER242
[DEBUG] env: USERPROFILE=C:\Users\AL-AWAL
[DEBUG] env: VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
[DEBUG] env: WINDIR=C:\WINDOWS
[DEBUG] env: WIX=C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\
[DEBUG] Executing command line: [C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe, /c, build_app.bat]
9 File(s) copied
        1 file(s) copied.
detecting required modules
detected modules: java.base,java.desktop,jdk.jfr,jdk.unsupported
manual modules: jdk.crypto.ec
==creating java runtime image==
==creating java package==
WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.jpackage
java.io.IOException: Command [C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe, -nologo, C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.incubator.jpackage10546670029502596189\config\bundle.wxf, -ext, WixUtilExtension, -arch, x64, -out, C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.incubator.jpackage10546670029502596189\wixobj\bundle.wixobj]in C:\Users\AL-AWAL\AppData\Local\Temp\jdk.incubator.jpackage10546670029502596189\images\win-msi.image\JPackageScriptFX exited with ?? code
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:751)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

and this is the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.dlsc.jpackagefx</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <javafx.version>14.0.1</javafx.version>
        <jmetro.version>11.6.12</jmetro.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>jpackagefx-main</module>
        <module>jpackagefx-module1</module>
        <module>jpackagefx-module2</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmetro</artifactId>
            <version>${jmetro.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- The following exclusions are necessary to override all hard coded dependencies -->
                <!-- on outdated or not needed external libaries -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>14</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm working on JDK 14.0.2 with maven and tried to package the project with jdk 15 and get the same error, and I complete all the Prerequisites that the repository on GitHub want and I can't find any solution to this error.

this is the repository that I take the project from https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error is saying that `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe` failed (that tool is executed by jpackage behind the scenes I believe). Unfortunately it just says exited with `???` code. Does running Maven with the `-e` or even `-X` switch give any more information pertinent to the problem?

Comment: I updated the post with output and -X switched and I still don't know what the error is about.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solution but here is what you could try:

1. I had problems with jpackage jdk 15 on MacOS. With jdk 16 it worked. So you could try jdk 16.
2. You could use jpackage to just create the image and not the installer. Then you could use the WiX Toolset to create the msi by yourself.